# How can I calculate the components of a 3D vector after it has been rotated

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have a 3D vector, with the knowledge of its current 3 components and therefore can calculate its magnitude and direction cosines.
They may change but for the sake of the question they can be <1,3,-2>. The origin is at 0,0,0.

By rotating the vector by an angle, how can I find the components after the vector has been rotated by the angle theta. All axes may need to be rotated.

Note: The vector may be rotated in more then one angle at a time (angles α & γ might be rotated together and not separately)

Comment: What axis are you considering for the rotation?

Comment: All axes may need to be rotated

Comment: You’ve misunderstood @AugSB. For a 3-D rotation, you need more than just a single angle to specify a rotation. You also need a line about which the rotation takes place. That’s what be means by “axis.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotations around coordinate axes can be done using matrices. Let $\theta$ be the angle.

- Clockwise rotation around $x$-axis:
  $$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$
- Clockwise rotation around $y$-axis:
  $$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$
- Clockwise rotation around $z$-axis:
  $$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$

Of course, you can rotate around several axes. In that case, you just need to use the corresponding matrices kkeping the order. For instance, if you want to rotate $\alpha$ around $y$-axis first and then $\beta$ around $x$-axis:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x'' \\ y'' \\ z'' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\beta & -\sin\beta \\ 0 & \sin\beta & \cos\beta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\beta & -\sin\beta \\ 0 & \sin\beta & \cos\beta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos\alpha & 0 & -\sin\alpha \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin\alpha & 0 & \cos\alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$